# How to open default keyboard emojicons layout?

Tags: android, keyboard, emoji

I am building an Android app for OS level kitkat and above. 
I want to open keyboard with default emojicons on button click.
Can I show keyboard with direct emojicon layout?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to add it manually or, much easier, use library. I recommend Emojione

Comment: Thanks Kevin. But I don't want to use third party library.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether it is possible to directly open emoji keyboard you can refer some emoji keyboard library

https://github.com/chiragjain/Emoticons-Keyboard

https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon